# Do I need activities, services AND broadcast receivers?

Tags: android

Everywhere I look android programs are said to be built on three main components: Activities, Services, and Broadcast Receivers. So far I have Activities and Broadcast Receivers, but see no need for Services. Is this alright, or do I NEED to implement Services into my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't forced to have Services in your application. Services are only needed when your app needs to do something in the background. For instance a music player needs a Service that plays the music while the user is doing other things outside of the music player.

Answer (score 1):

What you need depends on what you want your application to do. If you have specific queries about how to implement certain aspects of your app's functionality, then ask a more detailed question.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't found a use for them then you probably don't need them.

They certainly do have their place though.